# postfix and heirloom-mailx problems

Tags: mail-server

Iv'e just installed postfix on my pi and wanted to set it up to send emails via my gmail account.

Ive followed [this tutorial](http://sirlagz.net/2013/02/18/how-to-automatically-emailing-motion-snapshots/), but

when i do `sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx` it doesn't appear to install anything, it just says `pi@raspberry ~ $ ts... 0%`

I try this echo 'hi' | mail -s Test , but get error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Comment: I think this **pi@raspberry ~ $ ts... 0%** is the pi freezing on the instillation. The **..0%** stays at 0% then the system writes over the line with **ts**, but doesn't clear the rest of the line. The SSH connection has become intermittent following the failed installation of heirloom-mailx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `apt-get clean` and it's now letting me install programs.